# is there a way how to limit who can view forks of a repository?

Tags: github

For a repository I own, it would be helpful to limit who can view the list of forks - both via the Github API and via the web interface. It should be possible to make the repository private, if that would help limiting the fork view. It would be sufficient to limit the view to owners/admins of the repository. Is there a way how this can be done?

Here's a bit of background: this is meant for automating student hand-overs of a task. The students would fork a repository and create changes in their forks. Once the deadline hits, a script would clone all student forks and run some sort of evaluation. I do not want students to know what are the other forks to prevent cheating this way.

Comment: Is the repository public or private?

Comment: This is something I am open to. If it was private, I'd send the invites to the students once the semester starts.